# Azure Portal VM ARM Template Deployment With KeyVault

Tags: powershell, azure, virtual-machines, password, azure-arm-template

I want to deploy a VM in Azure and store the local admin password in Keyvault. I was wondering if it is possible to **do the deployment through the Azure Portal**? I've added the required info to my **parameters file** but I'm still being forced to **manually enter the admin password**. I haven't seen any sites mention deploying through the portal so I was wondering if its even possible.

There is loads of content on how to **deploy using powershell and AzureCLI** but I'd like to ***avoid these*** since I'm uhanding over the install process to a client and I want it to be as simple as possible.

Comment: Not sure I understand.  If you are making the Key Vault secret a parameter, you can either set the default to the value you want so you don't have to type it in but can change it if needed or you can set the key vault secret value to a variable and it can't be changed.

Comment: I added the following but I'm still required to enter a password. If I don't I get an error message saying to fill in the text box:                                                               
             "adminPassword": {
    "reference":  {
              "keyVault":  {
                "id":  "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/debsstg-rg/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/keyvvault-01"
                },
              "secretName":  "AdminVMPWD"
           }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible to reference a secret in Key Vault through VM creation in the portal. You would need to use ARM templates or CLI/PS to create the VM to do this.